# Calculate exact month-difference between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=772b749d5314317e74e1c807b01f63f5)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    inventory_date DATE,
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    product_value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO inventory (inventory_date, product_name, product_value)
VALUES ('2020-10-19', 'Product_A', '400'),
       ('2020-10-22', 'Product_B', '400'),
       ('2020-11-20', 'Product_C', '900'),
       ('2020-11-25', 'Product_D', '300');
```

Expected result:

```
    product_name | months_in_inventory
    -------------+--------------------
    Product_A    |       2
    Product_B    |       1
    Product_C    |       1
    Product_D    |       0
```

I want to calculate the `months_in_inventory` by calculating the difference between a `fixed_date` and the `inventory_date`.

In the example the `fixed_date` is  `'2020-12-20'` and I am using it my query.

So far I am able to calculate the difference in days:

```
SELECT
    iv.product_name,
    '2020-12-20'::date - MAX(iv.inventory_date::date) AS days_in_inventory
FROM 
    inventory iv
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    1;
```

However, I could not figure out how to change it to a difference in month. Do you have any idea?

**NOTE**

I know that one way to approach this would be extracting the `month` from the `fixed_date` and `inventory_date` and subtract both numbers. However, this would not give me the correct result because I need it exactly based on the dates.

For example `Product_B` is only `1 month` in inventory because `2020-10-22` is not two months compared to `2020-12-20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `age()`.  If the value is always less than 12 months, then one method is:

```
SELECT iv.product_name,
       extract(month form age('2020-12-20'::date, MAX(iv.inventory_date::date))) AS months_in_inventory
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

A more accurate calculation takes the year into account:

```
SELECT iv.product_name,
       (extract(year from age('2020-12-20'::date, MAX(iv.inventory_date::date))) * 12 +
        extract(month from age('2020-12-20'::date, MAX(iv.inventory_date::date)))
       ) AS months_in_inventory
FROM inventory iv
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4f6367251f0833cd2701445b9856dac1) is a db<>fiddle.